# Parse values using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to get `src` url from all this html using python.

I had this code to get text:

```
avatar = html.find(class_ = "image-container image-container-player image-container-bigavatar")
print(avatar)
```

```
<div class="image-container image-container-player image-container-bigavatar"><a href="/players/1227965603"><img alt="twitch.tv/gh0stluko" class="image-player image-bigavatar" data-tooltip-url="/players/1227965603/tooltip" rel="tooltip-remote" src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/b6/b6e83cac75233208d4bb79811d768fdf17dbd46e_full.jpg" title="twitch.tv/gh0stluko"/></a></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want to find images, add `"img"` as the first argument to `find()`.

Then you can look at the `["src"]` attribute directly:

```
avatar = html.find("img", class_="...")
print(avatar["src"])
```